# Is there a canonical way to create a Site Index in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

By Site Index I don't mean SiteMap as in a way to expose a XML. But a classic A-Z book index-like to offer all of the contents(links) of your site.

Is there a best practice way to do this in ASP.NET MVC (=>4) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short; No.

If your site is database driven, you might be able to query your database for a list of pages/items, but you'd still need to work out the page URLs based on your routing set-up and AFAIK there is no built-in way to do this.

Comment: So a compromise would be to crawl all the links on the "Index" page and arrange them somehow without having more depth to it than that? You'd lose all the paging, embedded stuff I assume.

Comment: Yes I think crawling would be the only way, unless you have some other method to access your content.